DPI awareness for child process in Windows MSIX container
I'm currently deploying a third party executable alongside my own program inside a MSIX package. The 3rd party program is launched via a system command inside a new process group and without a console.
Normally, when running directly under Windows, I can set a registry value under 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers' with the path of the 3rd party .exe to '~ HIGHDPIAWARE' to launch it in DPI aware mode. But this only works when the 3rd party program is installed outside of my MSIX.
My guess was that it had to do with the virtualized registry, but setting the correct registry values inside the MSIX sandbox didn't work either. Also embedding a manifest in my as well as the 3rd party .exe had no effect. Even setting "__COMPAT_LAYER=HighDpiAware" had no effect.  Did somebody get something similar to work inside MSIX?
